# spirals around cone

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I have multiple spirals running around a cone. The spirals are

$$r_\Delta = r_b - r_t$$
$$x(z) = r_b \cos(z) - r_\Delta z \cos(z)$$
$$y(z) = r_b \sin(z) - r_\Delta z \sin(z)$$
$$d(z) = \text{diameter} \frac{r_\Delta (1-z) + r_t}{r_b}$$

While the diameter of the spirals is proportional to the diameter of the cone, the distance between the spirals is not. This is a desired attribute though.

I know I need to wrap the $z$ in $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ but I am not quite sure with what.

How do I need to adjust the equations to get a proportional diameter *and* distance of the spirals?

[image: spirals cone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me rewrite the equations without changing the result:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
r_t  &=& r_b - r_\Delta \\
r(z) &=& r_b - r_\Delta z \\
x(z) &=& r(z) \cos(z) \\
y(z) &=& r(z) \sin(z) \\
d(z) &=& \frac{r_\Delta (1-z) + r_b - r_\Delta}{r_b} = \frac{r(z)}{r_b} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

The equations for $x$ and $y$ show that $2r(z)$ is the diameter of the
cone at the point $(x(z), y(z)),$ and the last equation shows that
the diameter of the spiral is proportional to $2r(z)$, so that part works.

In order for the spirals to be spaced proportionally to the diameter of
the cone, the projection of the spirals onto the $x,y$ plane will need
to satisfy the same condition, that is, the distance to the next spiral
from a any given point on any spiral needs to be proportional to the 
distance from the origin to the given point.

You wrote an equation for an Archimedean spiral in the $x,y$ plane;
in polar coordinates, what you have is $r = r_b - r_\Delta \theta.$
The spiral you need in the $x,y$ plane is a logarithmic spiral,
something of the form $r = r_0 e^{\kappa\theta}.$

Instead of making everything an explicit function of $z$,
let's parameterize using the polar angle, $\theta$,
and create a logarithmic spiral.
That is, we want

$$\begin{eqnarray}
r(\theta) &=& r_0 e^{\kappa\theta} \\
x(\theta) &=& r(\theta) \cos(\theta) \\
y(\theta) &=& r(\theta) \sin(\theta) \\
d(\theta) &=& \frac{r(\theta)}{r_b} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now the only problem is to decide what the $z$ coordinate should be
at each point on a spiral.
In order to make the spiral follow the surface of a cone, we need $z$
to be a linear function of $r$ (but not proportional to $r$, as long
as you require the vertex of the cone to be on the positive $z$-axis rather
than at the origin).
You have the vertex of the cone at $\left(0,0,\frac{r_b}{r_\Delta}\right)$
and you also have $r = r_b$ when $z = 0$;
to preserve those measurements (that is, to maintain the same shape
and position of the cone), we can put

$$z(\theta) = \frac{r_b}{r_\Delta} - \frac{1}{r_\Delta} r(\theta).$$

This fully defines the variables $x,$ $y,$ $z,$ and $d$ with which you
describe your spirals.

Comment: Really impressive response, David. Just the pointer to use a logarithmic spiral would have been enough to make me happy. I still have a few problems though. The question is what $r_0$ and $k$ should be. Using $r_0 = r_t$ and a try-and-error value for $k$ got me a spiral that is very close to what I need. But you lost me at $z(\theta)$ which is not always positive when trying it out.

Comment: Here is a visualisation http://i.imgur.com/tZC1P53.png

Comment: I would love to accept your answer but using polar coordinates doesn't really work so well for me. It looks I really need the explicit function of $z$ for my use case.

Comment: Actually - I think you answered the questions correctly. I still have some more questions. And for those I opened another question to better address them. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350052/logarithmic-spiral-around-cone-stump